# how can i fix this u-boot issue?

Tags: mobile, bootloader, u-boot

even from a freshly cloned copy of u-boot i get a error that says

Include/config_distro_bootcmd.h:319:2: error expected ')' before 'BOOT_TARGET_DEVICES_refrenves_USB_without_CONFIG_CMD_USB'

it does this reliably every time i make a change to .config from make menuconfig right after running both make clean and make mrproper. you can find the u-boot fork i made/i'm using here: https://github.com/yeetus-cpu/u-boot-lg-k20  although it is unfinished work

tried cloning fresh copy of u-boot
ran both make clean and make mrproper multiple times
was expecting to successfully compile and give me u-boot.bin

Comment: Did you read the **README** file? The section titled "Building the Software" mentions typing `make NAME_defconfig` (where NAME is for your board).

Comment: Doing this simply returns that it cannot find the defult configuration

Comment: "*Doing this simply returns that it ...*" -- Your terse summations are not informative. Instead of using ambiguous pronouns, post the actual terminal dialogue (i.e. the command(s) you typed in and the responses obtained). Also provide your host environment/system. Otherwise I vote to close for lack of detail.

Comment: by "this" its $ ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- make, also running on ubuntu 20.04. as for terminal output excluding it building tools https://pastebin.com/KYtu7yK3

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the error message says, you need to enable CONFIG_CMD_USB in your build, to go along with other options (that are likely enabled from whatever config / board you started from).

Comment: I am unable to find this option when I change architecture to arm

Comment: Then you probably need to look around at other parts of your .config file and see what's inconsistent where, or what your missing dependency is.

Comment: Well I'm pretty new to this stuff so idk what's wrong and right but as far as I could tell nothing seemed majorly wrong